# Editing the [date-format] tag

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46855551/python-change-a-date-format-in-dataframe) that had the tag [`date-format`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/date-format/info). The tag reads:

> `DateFormat` is a Java Standard Edition library class which provides utility methods to parse and format dates.

However of the [1,770](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/date-format) questions using this tag, only [480](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/date-format+java) of them also contain the  `java` tag. Is this something that should be put in the edit queue/changed? It's *technically* not wrong, but it seems pretty ambiguous to users on how to use it correctly.

Comment: I'm questioning whether we need the tag at all.

Comment: Should we give it the [burn](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/burninate-request/info) ;)? (in all honesty, probably not)

Comment: Well, I don't know. I don't think it is a worthwhile tag, but there is no consensus at this point on whether or not it should exist. I have no investment in the matter, so am unlikely to post a burnination request, but if you choose to do so then I would suggest reading [What is the process for tag removal (burnination)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination) before going forward. Make sure to include your reasoning against the criterion.

Comment: There is [tag:date-formatting], so this tag was misused

Answer (score 2):

As is the case with a lot of meta tags, someone picked *their* use case for it and put it in.

Most languages have some form of date formatting function. So saying this is a Java-only tag is incorrect. I see multiple languages using this tag. More importantly, the usage of this tag is not vague and the meaning is always the same, so it's not a good candidate for burnination.

I say we just edit the Java portions out of the excerpt and call it good. If there's a dire need for a Java-only tag, we can always make [java-date-format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-date-format), but I don't see any real need for that.

Comment: Ambiguity *is not* the only criteria for burnination.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem and came to meta to propose fixing it.

As things stand, we have ~1500 questions that are using [date-format] incorrectly (based on its description) and we have a tag that clearly invites misuse, presumably because it's name is not explicit enough.

I see three possible solutions...

1. Burn the tag - I do not agree intend to do this as I believe the tag still has value
   and can be fixed,
2. Merge [date-format] with [date-formatting].  I have no opinion on which tag name is best to keep, but would definitely keep the description from date-formatting, so date-format would cease to exist as a Java-specific tag,
3. For all ~1500 questions that do not also include the [java] tag and therefore probably use the tag incorrectly, change them to use [date-formatting], which would leave the ~500 that are probably using it correctly as-is.

I propose to proceed with #2.

Comment: I believe that what I propose is in the same direction as the answer by @Machavity.

Comment: Also cc @ajeetkanojia as the top answerer for the [date-format] tag, but I think user references like that don't work unless the user has participated in this question?